# Format of a permutation of a python dictionary

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, permutation

Hi I have this code...

```
x = {'stack': ['2', '3'], 'overflow': ['1', '2']}
for i in x.values():
    heroes = {x[0]:x[1:] for x in permutations(i)}
    print heroes
```

This gives me...

```
{'3': ('2',), '2': ('3',)}
{'1': ('2',), '2': ('1',)}
```

Later on in my program I need the values of the keys to be in list form, not tuple form. So the result I need is  this...

```
{'3': ['2'], '2': ['3']}
{'1': ['2'], '2': ['1']}
```

How can I modify my code to give me this result while maintaining efficieny?
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
heroes = {x[0]:list(x[1:]) for x in permutations(i)}
```

Comment: Thanks alot works like a charm. One question, will this casting take a toll on my program if I have dictionaries with 100000+keys?

Comment: @Clay, OF course this extra step takes extra time, but if you need lists you can't avoid it. Impossible to say how much "toll" this has on your program without seeing the rest